# What is part 53119 supposed to represent?

Tags: part-identification

[This](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=53119&in=S) part appears in 50 sets, but of particular interest is what it's supposed to represent. Is it a bag of trash, or animal faeces?

In Minifig series 19, dog sitter appears with 1x 53119 where it appears to imply a doggie doo-doo.

[image]

But it's also used in many other sets where doggy doo-doo wouldn't be appropriate/fit the theme. It also makes a good fairy cake icing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For an attempt at an objective answer, I went though all sets released in 2019 or 2020 with this part (13 sets total), and looked to see what the part represents.

The results:

- Brown in [col19-9](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col19-9): Dog poo
- Brown in [11940](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11940): Possibly poo, maybe just a lump of dirt
- Brown in [41429](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41429): Human poo
- Brown in [75969](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75969): Cupcakes/muffins
- Brown in [41422](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41422): Panda poo
- Brown in [71722](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=71722): Possibly poo, maybe just a lump of dirt
- White in [41431](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41431): Cupcakes
- White in [43180](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=43180): Ice-cream
- White in [43170](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=43170): Seashell
- White in [43183](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=43183): Decorations on a box. Mabe a seashell?
- White in [21322](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21322): Seashell? Foam?
- White in [43176](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=43176): Seashell
- White in [43188](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=43188): Contents of a pot. Soup?

So by my count we have: 3-5 poops, 4 foods and 2-4 seashells.

Comment: Based on the bag art for set 11940, I'd assume it's supposed to represent a catapult stone. (Also, after checking the build instruction for set 41429, I have to agree with your evaluation: the part is hidden deep inside the airplane build, completely out of sight and with no structural function, under the toilet seat in the plane's restroom in a cavity that looks like it represents a septic tank. It feels like whoever designed that set probably had a lot of fun hiding that little "easter egg" there. :D)

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, because it shows a good level or research and understanding of the question.

Comment: I just built 76389 (Hogwarts Chamber of Secrets), and the part is used as an Easter egg in one of the towers. I think it's supposed to represent Bassilisk poop.

Answer (score 8):

This question is hard to answer objectively.

It is a small "swirl" and like many pieces, represents whatever the designer/player wants it to. It comes in white (where as you noted, it is usually a cake icing or a rock) and in brown, where it looks like it is primarily a poo. But it can also represent a decorative element like a flourish.

Comment: Perhaps the best attempt at an objective answer would be that the imaged set is in fact the earliest release (and only release from 2019) with the part, so it is possible that "dog poo" was the original intention for this part (altough it is likely that other sets with other uses were in the pipeline).

Answer (score 6):

As Fredric Mention in [his answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/17165/13390), what this piece represents is up to the imagination of the creator. Indeed it is used for several things in official sets, often as a cupcake topping, icecream, seashell, or dog poop.

A few interesting uses:

- [marshmallow](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41683-1)
- [narwhal horn](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41928-1)
- [hermit crab shell](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=col21-3)

And [this set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=41440-1) uses a brown one as a cupcake, but also as a dog...

Answer (score 1):

Two dogs, a shovel and minifig's expression pretty much suggest that the subject of this question is *poop*.

Comment: For 1 of the 50 sets, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely represents faeces in a lot of sets. Children think poo is funny. Most of Lego's customers are children and Lego caters to its customers taste...